# Getting stuck while creating a new plugin project in liferay 6.2, facing some kind of ivy setting issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am getting stuck while creating a new plugin project in liferay, eclipse get stuck everytime and console displaying only [ivy:resolve] message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `Ivy resolve` process inside of the Liferay Plugins SDK is failing when it tries to create a new process.

Go into your Liferay Plugins SDK folder and open the `ivy-settings.xml` file. Notice that it points to some online repositories. It seems that your system is having trouble connecting to those remote repositories. See the log messages about the failing certificates (when its trying to connect to the https:// server of jboss repository ).

Maybe will be any special configuration required for connecting to those repositories, proxy...

Try from [here](http://files.liferay.org.es/staged/public-files/liferayide/dependencies/files/ivy-cache.zip)

Comment: Its not only me, some other people also facing same issue these days with LR 6.2, in my system 6.1 is working perfectly.

Comment: Try from [here](http://files.liferay.org.es/staged/public-files/liferayide/dependencies/files/ivy-cache.zip)

Comment: the link you gave displaying error 404 URL not found.

Comment: if you are trying to say, to download ivy chache and put it into sdk folder, i already did it but nothing happening!

Comment: Current versions of the Liferay SDK use Ivy, and you need a cache. If you're offline this can't be built (downloaded). With 6.1 there was no ivy, thus no ivy-related problems.